# Problema no SDK android

Tags: android, eclipse, instalador

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento para `Android` e de cara me apareceu um erro que acho que seja no `SDK Android` ou alguma configuração que fiz errado. Toda vez que inicio o `Eclipse` me aparece essa mensagem. Essa mensagem começou a aparecer depois que eu configurei `Android Virtual Decives (AVD)`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Considerando que a tool oficial suportada pelo time do Android é o Android Studio e que wearables são elementos muito recentes, a chance disso dar problema no eclipse é grande. Recomendo fortemente que, ou mude para o Android Studio ou desinstale features de wearables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o `Android` Studio ele tem suporte total ao `Android` e é passivel da utilização dos plugins da `jetbrains`, o Google não fornece mais suporte ao `ADT` (logo é possivel que este não esteja suportando o `Android Wear`)(plugin do eclipse para desenvolver `Android`), logo o `ADT` tende a não suportar as novas APIs do `Android` (que atualmente esta na revisão 22).

Nota sobre ADT:

> Note: If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android
>   Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to
>   Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, see Migrating to Android Studio.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html